# flask/Jinja2 escaping backslash from json

Tags: flask, jinja2

i have text field in postgresql which was saved as Json.
I am running query.all() and then passing the result the template.(the result is multiple rows with particular field in json)

Inside the template/jinja2 in running a for look to print the required field which looks like this.

Is there a way to have this available as a json in jina2?

```
"{\"base\": {\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"Traditional Pulao Rice\"}, \"dessert\": {\"id\": 9, \"name\": \"Ladoo\"}, \"protein\": {\"id\": 5, \"name\": \"Chicken Malai\"}, \"side\": {\"id1\": 7, \"id2\": 8, \"name1\": \"Channa Chaat\", \"name2\": \"Baked Sweet Potato\"}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json.loads on your available json and then you can use it in Jinja.

```
eg : json.loads("{\"base\": {\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"Traditional Pulao Rice\"}, \"dessert\": {\"id\": 9, \"name\": \"Ladoo\"}, \"protein\": {\"id\": 5, \"name\": \"Chicken Malai\"}, \"side\": {\"id1\": 7, \"id2\": 8, \"name1\": \"Channa Chaat\", \"name2\": \"Baked Sweet Potato\"}}")
```